# Use the Gnome Main Menu without a panel?

Tags: gnome, menu, docky

I really like docky for managing my applications but don't want to crowd it too much with pointless apps.

I would like to add an icon to open the Gnome Main Menu (Applications, Place, System etc) to docky if possible?

If this is not possible is there anything that can achieve similar results?

I tried using dockbarx on the panel which works nicely but isn't the best looking.

Thanks

Comment: Figured I could just use ALT + F1 to access the menu. Cardapio looks nice though I will give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Try `Cardapio`

[image]

**1. Add the PPA and then update:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cardapio-team/unstable
sudo apt-get update
```

**2. Open the `Ubuntu Software center` and Install `Cardapio` for docky :** 
[image]

**3.Done, Enjoy!**

Comment: Ah, we've posted the answer in the same time :)

Comment: Opps !...... :)

Comment: off topic, here is that conky? you have on the top right corner? if it is would you share your config?

Comment: No it is a clock screenlet. I can give you the theme, add the clock and then choose the theme from the properties.

Answer (score 2):

So is your question "Use the Gnome Main Menu without a panel?" or "I would like to add an icon to open the Gnome Main Menu (Applications, Place, System etc) to docky if possible?" ?

I'll answer the second one. You can't use the GNOME Main Menu in Docky as far as I know, but you can use Cardapio, an alternative to GNOME Main Menu with many useful features. For more about Cardapio, see [here](https://launchpad.net/cardapio).

[image]

To use Cardapio with Docky, add the PPA and install Cardapio and the Cardapio Docky Helper:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cardapio-team/unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cardapio cardapio-docky
```

Then enable Cardapio from the Docky helpers list. Now when you click the Docky anchor icon, it should launch Cardapio.

From [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/cardapio-menu-update-brings-docky.html).